# Hlookup with sumproduct where it looksup a date value then sums all the values up to that date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a cover page where someone would enter in a date. I want to create a formula that looks at another table where it would sum all the values before that date. For example, when they type in  10/27/2019 it goes to the table finds 10/27/2019 then returns back all the values(in the next column over) before that date.

multiple vlookup and hlookup combinations with sum product.

```
10/18/2019  5000.00
10/19/2019  5000.00
10/20/2019  5000.00
10/21/2019  5000.00
10/22/2019  5000.00
10/23/2019  5000.00
10/24/2019  5000.00
10/25/2019  5000.00
10/26/2019  5000.00
10/27/2019  5000.00
10/28/2019  5000.00
```

A year to date sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&C1)
```

Where B:B has the values to sum and A:A the dates.  C1 would be the inputted date.

[image]

Comment: Is there a short way to produce such pictures? Or are you making screenshots and cutting them with paint?

Comment: @OverflowStacker I just hit windows-Ctrl-S and then grab the screen part I want.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that. This way one can show much more than the cell area copy and pasted from excel. Nice.